# Azure data lake connection with data factory custom activity

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have a problem with custom activity in azure data factory.
I want to connect to azure data lake within it. 
I am using following namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
```

And here is my code:

```
    public ConnectDataLakeStore(string applicationId, string applicationSecretKey, string tenantId)
    {
        var credentials = new ClientCredential(applicationId, applicationSecretKey);
        var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, credentials).Result;
        var fileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);
    }
```

And I get the following exception:

```
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.Models.AdlsErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store.FileSystemOperations.<ListFileStatusWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

When I run custom activity in local environment everything works fine. Problem occurs after deployment to azure. I also gave all possible permissions to ad application.

Any hints?

Comment: Resolved. .NET Framework version should be <= 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather from your comment above that you've already solved this. But still thought it worth adding a little more detail for future peeps with similar issues.

First create a credential using your service principal and domain details.

Method:

```
    private static ServiceClientCredentials AuthenticateAzure(string domainName, string clientID, string clientSecret)
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
        return ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domainName, clientCredential).Result;
    }
```

Maybe get the values from your library config or project properties.

```
var creds = AuthenticateAzure(domainName, appId, appPass);
```

Next create an instance of the data lake account manager or file system manager depending on what you need.

```
    private static DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient adlsFileSystemClient;
    private static DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient adlsAccountManagementClient;

    adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);
    adlsAccountManagementClient = new DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClient(creds);
```

Next create something like the below method to upload files to the data lake store.

The uploader will perform faster than the create file method.

```
    private static void UploadFile(string srcFilePath, string destFilePath, string accName, bool force = true)
    {
        var parameters = new UploadParameters(srcFilePath, destFilePath, accName, isOverwrite: force);
        var frontend = new DataLakeStoreFrontEndAdapter(accName, adlsFileSystemClient);
        var uploader = new DataLakeStoreUploader(parameters, frontend);
        uploader.Execute();
    }
```

Sources:

**ADF Custom Activities**
https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/11/creating-azure-data-factory-custom-activities/

**ADL Auth**
https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/12/azure-data-lake-authentication-from-azure-data-factory/

Hope this helps